# python compare column one with word vs column two with label

Tags: python, string, compare, sentence

I have two columns from two different csv. A column contains words. The other column contains sentences. I import the columns as a list. Now I want to find all sentences in which one of the imported words occurs. Then I want to write the sentence and the word back into a csv.

Does anyone have any idea how I need to design the comparison words vs sentences using Python?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: word-sentence_matches dictionary: _d = dict(); for word in words; for i, sentence in enumerate(senteces); if word in sentece: d.setdefault(word, []).append(i)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the basis of the two columns being separate Lists and you wanting a List to write back to a CSV then use something like:

```
l1= ['bill has a ball', 'tom has a toy', 'fred has a frog']

l2=['ball', 'frog']

sentences_with_words = []
for s in l1:
    for w in l2:
        if w in s:
            sentences_with_words.append([s, w])
  
print(sentences_with_words)
```